Can SMA (styrene maleic anhydride) resin be used as a dispersant in pigments?
I have checked many materials and they all say that styrene maleic anhydride polymer - SMA resin can be used as a dispersant for pigments. However, I am not very clear about which ester solvent is the best for dispersing pigments of different colors.

Which pigments?
